# Can JAXB maven plugin only generate sources if something has changed?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

What happens for me is that every time there is a maven build, all my files get regenerated. I don't want that since i have made no changes to my .xsd file and what happens is that, because they were regenerated, git treats them as there were changes to those files.

Here's my configuration:

```
<execution>
  <id>myExecution</id>
  <goals>
<goal>generate</goal>
  </goals>
   <configuration>
     <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/MySchema.xsd</schemaDirectory>
     <generatePackage>com.mypackage</generatePackage>
     <generateDirectory>src/main/java</generateDirectory>
     <episode>false</episode>
   </configuration>
</execution>
```

is there a way arround this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never ever write generated source into the src/main/java directory. Just use the default *generateDirectory* value (${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc) - it's automatically added to the compile sources.

It is best practice to place all artifacts generated by the build process into the maven target directory (aka ${project.build.directory}).

Also, I recommend that you use the [Codehaus JAXB-2 Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/) as it seems to be much better maintained.

Comment: thank you for the best practices, all comments are welcome, but that's just what this is - a comment. It does not really reply to my question.

Comment: It resolves the git problem because your source tree is no longer having it's files updated. You gitignore maven target directories, right?

Comment: you are completely right, that resolved all my issues.

Comment: Can someone point out what is the rationale behind the best practice of using the generated-sources directory inside target? The drawback is that the project will show compile errors inside an IDE (e.g. eclipse) until it is built using maven.

Comment: @Overflow, I believe that most modern versions of the Eclipse maven integration (m2e) will do this for you without a command line maven build. I have not tried it in many years though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for the same solution you need.

To avoid time consuming in recompile code each time, in maven i've created two profile.

The first profile is used only for re-create classes from XSD: the plugin is inside the profile

```
<profile>
  <id>create-from-xsd</id>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
       ... maven jax plugin ...
     </plugin>
  <plugins>
<profile>
```

and then the other profile without the plugin.

When I need jax-b, I select the profile 1 and the classes are generated;
In the other cases I use profile 2.